# Advanced DataGrid image renderer

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I need to develop Advanced Datagrid like the below attached image. So I had developed the Grid with some columns but do not know how to rendering the image in the result part of the grid. Any one please help me, how to rendering the images in the result part. c

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a8e193239b.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a8e193239b.jpg)

Comment: It takes a bit for it to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need is for the given itemRenderer to include an Image object.  You would set the .source property of the Image to data.imageURL (or some similarly named property on your data object).